# На каком сайте посоветуете изучать javascript

Tags: javascript

Я думаю на [этом](http://www.webmaster.ee/javascript/js.html) что скажете?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript с 0](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24923/javascript-%d1%81-0)

Answer (score 4):

javascript.ru

Answer (score 2):

На своём (том, который вы делаете или, вернее, пытаетесь делать).

Answer (score 1):

Я начинал изучение js по толстому самоучителю Wrox 2002 года. Сейчас он немного устарел, но базу давал изумительную, особенно радовали примеры кода, после которых шло объяснение "как это работает". Если есть более новое издание - очень советую.
А из сайтов могу посоветовать http://eloquentjavascript.net/ - там есть удобная консолька для исполнения и отладки примеров кода.

Answer (score 0):

я думаю если есть фундаментальные знания в программированиее то спокойно можно обойтись без книг. юзайте самую обыкновенную справку... сам ей пользуюсь
[качайте здесь](http://www.pelmeshka80.d9x.ru/php_css_html_manual.chm)

Здесь PHP_HTML_CSS_JS_VBScript_Perl_Flash_SSI
Это не весь список

Answer (score 0):

Мне понравился ответ, что изучать нужно на своем проекте, а еще лучше на коммерческом, на котором есть время для параллельного обучения.
Так для обучения хорошо подходит firebug, в котором вы можете сразу выполнять написанный код.
P.s. порадовал ie9. теперь там есть нечно похожее на firebug с аналогичной возможностью выполнение написанного кода! зачёт!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Вот здесь](http://helloworld.ru) всё доступно. Есть много туториалов, книг и т.д. и т.п.